# How to convert pandas groupby result into a consolidated dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have created a sample dataframe using the following, and have subsequently grouped its values as seen below:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Country': ['United States', 'United States', 'United States', 'India', 'India', 'Australia', 'Australia',
                    'Australia',
                    'Australia'],
        'State': ['New York', 'California', 'California', 'Karnataka', 'Punjab', 'Victoria', 'Victoria', 'Victoria',
                  'Victoria'],
        'Team': ['Globetrotters', 'Lakers', 'Lakers', 'Beasts', 'Steelers', 'United', 'United', 'United', 'United'],
        'Player': ['Dudley', 'James', 'Davis', 'Kumar', 'Singh', 'Smith', 'Smith', 'Smith', 'Jones'],
        'Status': ['Normal', 'NBA Legend', 'NBA', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'NBA', 'Normal']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

columns = ['Country', 'State', 'Team', 'Player', 'Status']
groupings = df.groupby(columns).size()

print(groupings)
```

The output of the above code snippet is as follows:

```
Country        State       Team           Player  Status    
Australia      Victoria    United         Jones   Normal        1
                                          Smith   NBA           1
                                                  Normal        2
India          Karnataka   Beasts         Kumar   Normal        1
               Punjab      Steelers       Singh   Normal        1
United States  California  Lakers         Davis   NBA           1
                                          James   NBA Legend    1
               New York    Globetrotters  Dudley  Normal        1
```

I would like to convert this result into a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
[{'Country': 'Australia', 'State': 'Victoria', 'Team': 'United', 'Jones': 1, 'Smith': 3, 'Normal': 3, 'NBA': 1, 'Total': 4},
 {'Country': 'India', 'State': 'Karnataka', 'Team': 'Beasts', 'Kumar': 1, 'Normal': 1, 'Total': 1},
 {'Country': 'India', 'State': 'Punjab', 'Team': 'Stealers', 'Singh': 1, 'Normal': 1, 'Total': 1},
 {'Country': 'United States', 'State': 'California', 'Team': 'Lakers', 'Davis': 1, 'James': 1, 'NBA': 1,'NBA Legend': 1, 'Total': 2},
 {'Country': 'United States', 'State': 'New York', 'Team': 'Globetrotters', 'Dudley': 1, 'Normal': 1, 'Total': 1}]
```

Please note that in the above sample output, the combination of Country, State and Team are all unique per dictionary. Also, the Player and Status columns are no longer retained, and are instead replaced by their actual values and counts. Finally, a new Total column is added (sum of all the players/statuses per Country + State + Team combination).

I know this is a bit of a complicated question, but hopefully I am clear in my explanations and requirements. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It seems like you are asking people to do your work for you.  You should rephrase your question to highlight where you are stuck.  e.g if you say how do I separate out `Status` into separate columns, then people would point you to `DataFrame.unstack`, or maybe how can I skip fields with `NA` when converting dataframe to dictionary records, etc ...

Comment: @suvayu I am still relatively new to stackoverflow so appreciate your feedback. Will do so with my next questions for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this code using `reindex`, `repeat`, `reset_index`, `get_dummies`, `groupby` and `to_dict`:

```
groupings = groupings.reset_index()
groupings.columns = [i if i != 0 else 'Total' for i in groupings.columns]
groupings = groupings.reindex(groupings.index.repeat(groupings['Total'])).reset_index(drop=True)
groupings['Total'] = 1
print(pd.get_dummies(groupings, columns=['Player', 'Status'], prefix='', prefix_sep='').groupby(['Country', 'State', 'Team'], as_index=False).sum().to_dict('records'))
```

Output:

```
[{'Country': 'Australia', 'State': 'Victoria', 'Team': 'United', 'Total': 4, 'Davis': 0, 'Dudley': 0, 'James': 0, 'Jones': 1, 'Kumar': 0, 'Singh': 0, 'Smith': 3, 'NBA': 1, 'NBA Legend': 0, 'Normal': 3}, {'Country': 'India', 'State': 'Karnataka', 'Team': 'Beasts', 'Total': 1, 'Davis': 0, 'Dudley': 0, 'James': 0, 'Jones': 0, 'Kumar': 1, 'Singh': 0, 'Smith': 0, 'NBA': 0, 'NBA Legend': 0, 'Normal': 1}, {'Country': 'India', 'State': 'Punjab', 'Team': 'Steelers', 'Total': 1, 'Davis': 0, 'Dudley': 0, 'James': 0, 'Jones': 0, 'Kumar': 0, 'Singh': 1, 'Smith': 0, 'NBA': 0, 'NBA Legend': 0, 'Normal': 1}, {'Country': 'United States', 'State': 'California', 'Team': 'Lakers', 'Total': 2, 'Davis': 1, 'Dudley': 0, 'James': 1, 'Jones': 0, 'Kumar': 0, 'Singh': 0, 'Smith': 0, 'NBA': 1, 'NBA Legend': 1, 'Normal': 0}, {'Country': 'United States', 'State': 'New York', 'Team': 'Globetrotters', 'Total': 1, 'Davis': 0, 'Dudley': 1, 'James': 0, 'Jones': 0, 'Kumar': 0, 'Singh': 0, 'Smith': 0, 'NBA': 0, 'NBA Legend': 0, 'Normal': 1}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Your output is slightly different from what I am looking for, but I guess it will do. One thing that is wrong in your output is that Smith is returning count of 1 when it is in fact 2. Could you please help to look into this?

Comment: @nb123 Just a question.. Why is `Smith` supposes to be `2`?

Comment: In my actual dataset, a team can have two or more people with the same name. Hence, in my sample output above, I have given Smith as 2 to represent such cases. I hope that clarifies?

Comment: @nb123 If you try this code in your actual dataset, it should work

Comment: I have modified my examples above slightly. You will notice that the code fails when 2 Smiths are mapped to Normal. Please give it a go and you will see what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: I am inclined to accept this answer, provided the above can be rectified. Thank you!

Comment: @nb123 Didn't see your comments sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235053/discussion-between-nb123-and-u11-forward).

Comment: @nb123 check out my explanation in chat.

Answer (score 1):

First I change your groupby a little:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

def list_counts(l):
    return dict(Counter(l))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

groupings = df.groupby(
    [
        "Country",
        "State",
        "Team",
    ],
    as_index=False,
).agg(Total=("Player", "size"), Players=("Player", list), Status=("Status", list))
```

Then I use the Counter to count the players and status:

```
groupings["Players"] = groupings["Players"].apply(list_counts)
groupings["Status"] = groupings["Status"].apply(list_counts)
```

Then I transform the Dataframe to a dict - and remove the Player and Status level from the dict. As well I move Total to the end of the dict.

```
res = groupings.to_dict(orient="records")

for r in res:
    players = r["Players"]
    status = r["Status"]
    total = r["Total"]
    r.pop("Total")
    r.pop("Players")
    r.pop("Status")
    for i in players:
        r[i] = players[i]
    for i in status:
        r[i] = status[i]
    r["Total"] = total
```

Output:

```
[{'Country': 'Australia',
  'State': 'Victoria',
  'Team': 'United',
  'Smith': 2,
  'Jones': 1,
  'Normal': 3,
  'Total': 3},
 {'Country': 'India',
  'State': 'Karnataka',
  'Team': 'Beasts',
  'Kumar': 1,
  'Normal': 1,
  'Total': 1},
 {'Country': 'India',
  'State': 'Punjab',
  'Team': 'Steelers',
  'Singh': 1,
  'Normal': 1,
  'Total': 1},
 {'Country': 'United States',
  'State': 'California',
  'Team': 'Lakers',
  'James': 1,
  'Davis': 1,
  'NBA Legend': 1,
  'NBA': 1,
  'Total': 2},
 {'Country': 'United States',
  'State': 'New York',
  'Team': 'Globetrotters',
  'Dudley': 1,
  'Normal': 1,
  'Total': 1}]
```

Alternative solution - more condensed but same principle. Output as requested but structured a little different:

```
from collections import Counter


def list_counts(l):
    return dict(Counter(l))


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
res = (
    df.groupby(
        [
            "Country",
            "State",
            "Team",
        ],
        as_index=False,
    )
    .agg(
        Total=("Player", "size"),
        Players=("Player", list_counts),
        Status=("Status", list_counts),
    )
    .to_dict(orient="records")
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This code works but does not seem very efficient unfortunately. What are your thoughts on how we could optimise this?

Comment: @nb123 Agree, and it is a complex operation. You want to sum on three groupings (team, player and status). As well you had special requirements to the format of the dictionary (the last part with the for loops). I have provided an alternative condensed version. Efficient, but the dict format is a little different. Can you live with that?

Comment: Thanks @Henrik Bo. I have upvoted your answer:)